# About Maven Mate

Tags: mavensmate

I have installed subline text 3 and configured it.and configured maven mate as well. But when i am going on maven mate menu and than new project. new project window is not opening.when i am going to maven mate console it is showing below error:

MAVENSMATE: mm command:

MAVENSMATE: "C:\Users\prabhatranjan\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\MavensMate\mm\mm.exe" -c SUBLIME_TEXT_3 --ui -o new_project
MAVENSMATE: response from mm: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 11, in

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\pkg_resources", line 34, in

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\email.parser", line 12, in

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\email.feedparser", line 27, in

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\email.message", line 16, in

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\email.charset", line 13, in

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\email.base64mime", line 40, in

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\email.utils", line 27, in

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\random", line 885, in

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\random", line 97, in **init**

File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ghook\build\mm\out00-PYZ.pyz\random", line 113, in seed

WindowsError: [Error -2146893795] Provider DLL failed to initialize correctly

MAVENSMATE failed to send community activity

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Mavensmate as well by navigating to:

[image]

Plugin doesn't work until you install the Mavensmate itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response.i am getting below error in my error log if i am creating new project .Loading MavensMate for Sublime Text
mm_installer -->
Calling mm_interface
OPERATION: new_project
{}